# how does @Rolesallowed works

Tags: java, roles, weblog

I am working on a project that has services that are annotated with @RolesAllowed.
I know this annotation defines roles that can access the method. But I am not sure where these roles are defined and how user will be added for different roles. I am using weblogic as application server.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to set roles, for example if you are using Shiro JDBC realm you can specify the query that get roles from username.

this example from the Application class

```
@Bean
public Realm realm() {

    JdbcRealm realm = new JdbcRealm();
    realm.setDataSource(dataSource);
    realm.setAuthenticationQuery("SELECT password FROM user_login WHERE username = ?");
    realm.setUserRolesQuery("SELECT role FROM user_role WHERE username = ?");
    realm.setPermissionsQuery("SELECT permission FROM role_permission WHERE role = ?");
    realm.setCredentialsMatcher(new HashedCredentialsMatcher(Sha512Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME));
    realm.setPermissionsLookupEnabled(true);
    return realm;
}
```

The short answer is the role is generally found by the realm using the login credential.
must of the time 
JDBC Realms have a default query like `select role_name from user_roles where username = ?"`

LDAP Realms will assign LDAP groups to Roles

...

Comment: Can you explain in general term. No idea what is Shiro JDBC.

Comment: Shiro : is a security framework from apache [https://shiro.apache.org/] <br> JDBC realm : Is a security realm based on Database. <br> i managed to find the specific link for weblogic. [https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/SCOVR/realm_chap.htm#i1031639] <br> good luck